# Minimum Scalar Product

Tags: c++, c++11, programming-challenge

Here's the problem statement for [Minimum Scalar Product](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32016/dashboard#s=p0)

> You are given two vectors v1=(x1,x2,...,xn) and v2=(y1,y2,...,yn). The scalar product of these vectors is a single number, calculated as x1y1+x2y2+...+xnyn.
>
>
> Suppose you are allowed to permute the coordinates of each vector as you wish. Choose two permutations such that the scalar product of your two new vectors
> is the smallest possible, and output that minimum scalar product.

Please review my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

int main() {
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        std::size_t n;
        std::cin >> n;
        if (n != 0) {
            int product = 0;
            std::vector<int> x(n);
            for (std::size_t x_index = 0; x_index < n; ++x_index) {
                std::cin >> x[x_index];
            }
            std::vector<int> temp(n);
            for (std::size_t t_index = 0; t_index < n; ++t_index) {
                std::cin >> temp[t_index];
            }
            sort(x.begin(),x.end());
            sort(temp.begin(),temp.end());
            std::vector<int> y(n);
            for (std::size_t y_index = 0; y_index < n; ++y_index) {
                y[y_index] = temp[temp.size()-1-y_index];
            }
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                product += x[i]*y[i];
            }
            std::cout << product << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make this code better and faster? Particularly without using an additional vector? And is there a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you should mention that your code takes advantage of the [Rearrangement inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) which states
that the scalar product of any permutation of the vectors 
\$ (x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \$ and \$ (y_1,y_2,...,y_n) \$ is minimal if the elements of one vector
are in increasing order and the elements of the other in decreasing order.

I see two possible simplifications: First, instead of reading the second
vector into a temporary vector, sorting it and then reversing it "manually", you can sort in decreasing order by supplying a comparator to the sort:

```
for (std::size_t y_index = 0; y_index < n; ++y_index) {
    std::cin >> y[y_index];
}
sort(y.begin(),y.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

Second, the scalar product can be computed with

```
#include <numeric>

int product = std::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), 0);
```